# What does arr1[..] == arr2[..] mean in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have been studying some tutorials on blockchains, where Rust is the go-to language.

Then, at some point, I found a comparison between two arrays, using a notation that I don't have a clue about.

I know that '..' is a range operation in Rust. Would it be a direct comparison of the size and content of two full arrays?

```
if somearray[..] == anotherarray[..] {
   return Ok(true);
}
```

I couldn't find any direct reference on the web, so I decided to ask here.

Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: They are really just two Bytes arrays. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 7):

`array[..]` is indexing the array using [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html). It returns the whole array, but as a slice instead of an array. This has (almost) the same effect as calling [`as_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html#method.as_slice).

As for the why, until Rust 1.47, [arrays could be only compared up to 32 elements](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/10/08/Rust-1.47.html#traits-on-larger-arrays). More than that you shall have converted them to slices. [Commit eff62069ad602090e8d27b83cffd9e77479ed4be](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/eff62069ad602090e8d27b83cffd9e77479ed4be) lifted this restriction, but this code was probably written before then, and the arrays were too large to use `==` without first converting into slices.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes, it's testing that both arrays are the same length and contain the same values in the same order.

The best way to figure these questions out is to look at the types, and the operations you're *actually* performing on them.

`somearray` and `anotherarray` are presumably [Arrays](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html) (`[T; N]`).
There is a tiny but crucial misunderstanding in your question - `..` is syntax sugar for a [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html) value, which when used as a slicing index (by invoking trait method `Index::index()`, or using the syntax sugar `[]` like your example), gives you a *[slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html)* of the entire array's contents.

`[T; N][..] -> [T]`. Array is a fixed-length (known at compile time) type, Slice is the dynamic length alternative.

The `==` syntax similarly desugars to the `eq()` method from the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq`. The slice type provides an [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%5BB%5D%3E) where the inner types already have a PartialEq implementation, and if you dig down to the bottom, you can verify that the std implementation does what you would expect: https://stdrs.dev/nightly/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/src/core/slice/cmp.rs.html#64

Comment: Oh, this clears it out in many levels. Thx.